# Looking for reference material in quantum algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations

I want to reconstruct some problems to take my study further deeper that are closely aligned with information retrieval in the form of quantum algebra. but I wonder if there are very limited books available in the Indian market. can anyone suggest some reference material about [quantum algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algebra)?

Comment: Related [mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290522)

Comment: @KyleKanos that is great but is there anything out there for more deep understanding?

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about the subject. I clicked on the Wiki link that was added to the post, saw the MO link and added it here.

Comment: @CADENTIC I have posted an answer with a broad and in-depth reference in mind. If you would like very specific topics, you'd have to revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great reference on the subject matter is [Quantum Groups and Their Representations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-60896-4). The authors, Klimyk and Schmüdgen cover a variety of areas. For instance, quantized universal enveloping algebras, quantized algebras of functions, q-oscillator algebras, their representations and corepresentations, and noncommutative differential calculus, are among the many topics explored in the book with potential physical and mathematical applications in mind.

The basic quantum groups, quantum algebras and their representations are given in detail with the necessary proofs and presented with explicit formulae. A number of topics and results from the more advanced general theory are developed and discussed as well, making it a very deep and cohesive presentation.